# Multiplication Digits Solver in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiplication

I am creating a program in Python that finds the digits that can match the letters of the following multiplication, for example:

OTTO x
____I
STOP
( meaning OTTO x I = STOP )

Here is the code I've been working on, but it doesn't seem to stop...

```
# OTTO x I = STOP

times = 1
digit_o = 0
digit_t = 0
digit_i = 1
digit_s = 0
digit_p = 0

concatenation_otto = str(str(digit_o) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_o))
concatenation_stop = str(str(digit_s) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_o) + str(digit_p))

def amend() :
    concatenation_otto = str(str(digit_o) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_o))
    concatenation_stop = str(str(digit_s) + str(digit_t) + str(digit_o) + str(digit_p))
amend()

print "working..."
while (concatenation_otto * digit_i == concatenation_stop) :
    while times == 7 :
        if times == 1 :
            digit_o += 1
            times += 1
            print digit_o + " / " + str(times)
            amend()
            break
        elif times == 2 :
            digit_t += 1
            times += 1
            amend()
            break
        elif times == 3 :
            digit_i += 1
            times += 1
            amend()
            break
        elif times == 4 :
            digit_s += 1
            times += 1
            amend()
            break
        elif times == 5 :
            digit_p += 1
            times += 1
            amend()
            break

        times == 1
        continue

print digit_o
print concatenation_otto + " x " + str(digit_i) + " = " + concatenation_stop
```

Please help and I hope you fully understood what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: *I am creating a program in Python* ... Continue

Comment: What multiplication?

Comment: Are you trying to solve "OTTO times I equals STOP", or "OTTO times (four underscores plus I) equals STOP"? Do the underscores represent the bar separating the multiplication from the solution, or are they supposed to be "fill in the blanks"?

Comment: @user5061 `OTTO X I = STOP`

Comment: Do you mean `(O * T * T * O) * I = S * T * O * P` or do you mean (Which I think is more likely) `I(1000O + 100T + 10T + O) = 1000S + 100T + 10O + P`? Any of which is off-topic not to do with programming.

Comment: I meant "OTT0 times I equals STOP." I forgot to say that the last "OTTO" character is actually a zero.  I understand that I have to create a continuous loop until the program finds the answer; but how do I do this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. Use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to create 5-permutations of the digits, then check the result.

```
import itertools

for O, T, I, S, P in itertools.permutations((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 5):
    OTTO = 1000 * O + 100 * T + 10 * T + O
    STOP = 1000 * S + 100 * T + 10 * O + P
    if OTTO * I == STOP:
        print(O, T, I, S, P)
        break
```